# Can I use platform event (which calls apex method) as alternative to future method?

Tags: apex, bestpractice, platform-event

Can I use platform event (which calls apex method) as an alternative to invoking future method from trigger? Is this against salesforce best practices?

Comment: What are you planning on using this implementation for? Have you looked at using [Queueable Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_queueing_jobs.htm) instead of `@future` methods?

Comment: the potential option for the orgs which are near future or queueable limits.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generally I wouldn't recommend it as a way of preforming delayed asynchronous processing that would otherwise be handled by future or queueable methods. That's just me thou and your extenuating circumstances may be different than mine.

A few reasons spring to mind for why this might not be a good idea.

The Apex Trigger for the event is still a trigger, so it can't make direct callouts like a future method can. Maybe that's OK if you are just after more Apex processing time, but...

Still on the trigger, it will likely get called for a collection of events under load. In which case, what have you gained if you have to process 200 events in the trigger. Last I checked you could actually get more than 200 events in the Apex trigger, so you might actually be worse off. I.e you could [see up to **2000** events](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/174047/102) in the trigger context. If you were having problems at 200 records it's going to be much harder at 2000.

See also:

- [Platform Event Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_event_limits.htm)

An applicable quote from [Jay Hurst](https://success.salesforce.com/0D53A000036UahF) (Director, Product Management) - my emphasis:

> What we are trying to solve with events **is not a way around limits with Apex or Callouts**, but rather a way to notify subscribers of events in real time. This does require that there is a subscriber listening (either on the Salesforce App Cloud, or as an external listener). 
>   What you do with those events as a subscriber is still in the developer domain.

---

I'd personally go with a custom object to act as a queue for the overflow work. Then have something come through that queue and process the work as resources become available.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, these details are super helpful. with all the details in answer, it makes sense to go with queue approach in case of running out of future or Queuable limit.

Answer (score 1):

You can, and for an event-driven architecture using platform events feels like the right approach. However, the end result for most use cases I'm guessing will be pretty much the same whether you use platform events, `@future` or `Queueable`.

The biggest design consideration is the cost of using platform events. Platform events are designed to be sold like Amazon SMS, so while you'll get some for free I recommend double-checking your expected volume against your licensed limit.

Also note that [testing platform event code is slightly different](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_event_apex_tests.htm) than testing `@future` or `Queueable` calls.